# apple mach o linker error xcode 6.1

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EntityImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in JSONParser.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_clsCommonEntity", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in JSONParser.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Error not going even after cleaning, Re opening xcode, deleting derived data

Comment: I got an idea for same is if we add a same static library to 2 diff library or project then this issue comes. Another reason if you are using MVC pattern then you need to build the lib each time you make changes in header file.

Comment: These errors are often missing/not imported classes.  Its pointing you to your `JSONParser.o` file so thats what you should be checking.  Im assuming this is a third party library you're using make sure the version you are using is compatible with 64 bit